# Derivation of Poisson PDF from Binomial: questions on a Wiki proof

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem) has a proof and I have questions regarding it.

a)
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} {n \choose k} p^k_n(1-p_n)^{n-k} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdots (n - k + 1)}{k!} \left ( \frac \lambda n\right)^k \left(1 - \frac \lambda n \right)^{n-k}
$$
**Question 1** how was the $(n -k +1)$ term in the numerator derived?

b)
$$
= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac {n^k + O(n^{k-1})}{k!} \frac {\lambda^k}{n^k} \left(1 - \frac \lambda n \right)^{n-k}
$$
c)
$$
= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac {\lambda^k}{k!} \left(1 - \frac \lambda n\right)^{n-k}
$$

**Question 2** how does form (b) become (c)?  Does $\frac {n^k + O(n^{k-1})}{n^k} = 1$ somehow?  If big-O $O(n^{k-1}) = (\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^{k-1}) \le C n^{k-1}$, then (b) becomes $\frac {n^k + Cn^{k-1}}{n^k} = 1 + C n^{-1}$.  I'm confused here.

Comment: @Nick There is no division sign in $n$ choose $k$.

Comment: $$\text{Note that } \binom n k = \frac{n!}{(n-k)! k!} = \frac{ \overbrace{\,n(n-1)(n-2) \cdots (n-k+1)\,}^\text{The number of factors here is $k.$} }{k!}. \qquad\qquad\qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy corrected thanks

Comment: @dole corrected

Comment: @MichaelHardy helpful!! Do you know what function $O$ represents?

Comment: @Nick : To say that $f(n) = O(n^{k-1})$ as $n\to\infty$ means that there is some positive number $C,$ not depending on $n$, such that for all sufficiently large values of $n$ one has $f(n) \le Cn^{k-1}. \qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: See big O notation.

Question 2:

We have
$$\frac {n!}{k!(n -k)!}=\frac {n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)...(n-k+1)}{k!}$$

This really is obvious ($n!$ is series of products from $n$ to one and $(n-k)!$ a series from $n-k$ to one), but we can also use induction to prove it. If $k=1$, then

$$\frac {n!}{k!(n -k)!}=\frac {n!}{1!(n -1)!}=\frac {n (n-1)!}{(n -1)!}=n=\frac{(n-k+1)}{k!}$$

Let now the relation hold for $k$, and we will show that this holds for $k+1$. We have

$$\frac {n!}{(k+1)!(n -(k+1))!}$$
$$=\frac {(n-k)n!}{(k+1)k!(n -k)!}$$
$$=\frac {n (n-1)(n-2)...(n-(k+1)+1)}{(k+1)!}$$

This gives the claim.

Comment: In the induction step $\frac {n!}{1! (n - 1)!} = \frac {n(n-1)}{(n-1)}$ how are these equal?

Comment: $n!=n(n-1)!$ almost by definition. Also, it is the base case, but ok...

Comment: In the $k+1$ step, should $k + 1$ be substituted for all occurrences?  You have $\frac {n!} {k!(n - (k+1))!}$ and I question if this should be $\frac {n!} {(k+1)!(n - (k+1))!}$.  I figured out Big O and updated the post.  Do you know the answer to question 2?

Comment: @Nick Fixed... The question 2 is straight forward. Just type zero in place of the $O$ term.

Comment: @Nick Note that in the limit $\frac{O(n^{k-1})}{n^k}C=0$, for any $C$. Since the limit converges, then the above follows.

Comment: Similar to what is in the OP $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (1 + \frac C n) = 1 + 0 = 1$. Thanks!